# Cannot Find HResult from WindowsAPICodePack

Tags: c#, windows-api-code-pack

I have been working on this for couple hours, searching everywhere can't couldn't find a solution.

I got an error message saying:

> アセンブリ 'Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' から型 'MS.WindowsAPICodePack.Internal.HResult'
>   を読み込めませんでした。

Which roughly translates into cannot read type blahblahblah.HResult from assembly blahblahblah.

I'm trying to get the thumbnail from a file, using `ShellFile.FromFilePath(f.FullName).Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmap`

The exception is thrown at `.Thumbnail`.

Any help to get me a transparent thumbnail would do, but I'm really looking for short answers.

Comment: What is the HResult number?

Comment: it says "cannot read/find the type HResult", which i had no problem finding under the reference...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by me dragging the dll file directly into the project, apparently that .dll file, for some reason that does not have the class i needed was used instead of the reference. After removing the dll file everything works.